# update, execute or render a jsf component based on some action of other component

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I was facing issues regarding rendering or executing the jsf components based on action of some other component.

What I am trying to do is:
load some data when the page is first loaded. so I wrote

```
<f:metadata>
<f:event listener="#{homeController.retrieveAllTagsForUser}"
    type="preRenderView" />
<f:event listener="#{homeController.populatePostsForUser}"
                type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

populatePostsForUser method first loads all the posts for the user as follows

```
public void populatePostsForUser() {
    EntityManager manager = applicationContext.getEntityManagerFactory()
            .createEntityManager();
    Query query = manager.createNamedQuery("Post.selectPostForUser");
    query.setParameter("user", this.getUser());
    this.posts = (List<Post>) query.getResultList();
    System.out.println("populatePostFOrUser called");
}
```

and after the page is loaded, I update the posts field in that method as follows

```
this.posts = (List<Post>)em.createNamedQuery("Post.selectPostsByTags").setParameter("tags", tags).getResultList();
    System.out.println("number of posts selected = " + this.posts.size());
    System.out.println("selected posts for this tag = " + this.posts);
    System.out.println("number of posts selected for tag = " + tags + " " + this.posts.size());
```

this updates the posts field successfully but after that, once again the same populatePostsForUser method is called. It is called everytime some component is re-rendered.

This is just an example for what I want to know. My Question is. How can I have control over the jsf components such that I can render/update/execute a jsf component on some ajax event of another component?

I would like to know the best ways to communicate between jsf components and render them according to our choice when ajax is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by doing some research and understood the difference between ajax execute and update from following link

https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/index.html